# Problems with showing a new paragraph

Tags: javascript

I am creating a game like rock,paper,scissors and everything is fine but I also want to show what the user has picked but I am not getting it, here is the code

```js
var paragraph = document.querySelector('p');

var assignClick = function enter code here(tag, pos) {
  tag.addEventListener('click', function() {
    playerChoice = pos;
    cpuChoice.init();
    paragraph.innerText = 'You chose:' + playerChoice;
    paragraph.innerText = 'The computer chose:' + cpuChoice.text;
    paragraph.innerText += '\n' + chooseWinner(playerChoice, cpuChoice.store);
    paragraph.innerText += '\n' + 'SCORE: ' + score;
  });

}
```

I am new to JavaScript but from my guessing something like paragraph.innerText = 'You chose:' + playerChoice; should do the work

Comment: `function enter code here`? What have you tried so far? It would also help if you could use the code formatting tool to help improve the readability of your question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. You should provide all of your relevant code. Since you're actively editing the look of the DOM, you should include the relevant HTML code also.

Comment: For Javascript check this out https://pastebin.com/fByn1tTZ  for HTML this https://pastebin.com/7HSMtEzu  THANKS A LOT FOR THE FAST REPLIES

Answer (score 0):

For creating a new paragraph element, you need to use document.createElement("p")(For more info check: [document.createElement](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp).

After creating the element you need to manually insert it into the dom using parent.appendChild() method (For more info check: [parent.appendChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

**Edit**

I think the following code will do the job for you:

```
 paragraph.innerText = 'The computer chose: ' + cpuChoice.text;
 paragraph.innerText += '\n'+'The player chose: ' +readable[playerChoice];
```

Comment: What i want to do is to add something like "You chose: " above or beyond that "The computer chose: "  here the image http://prntscr.com/lmsl13

Comment: var t = document.getElementById("p").textContent;
var y = document.createTextNode("This just got added");

t.appendChild(y);

Comment: doesnt work, i dont know how to implement it, doesnt do anything..... i need more guidance...

Comment: share your html/css and js code via a codepen link and I'll try to help you

Comment: For Javascript check this out pastebin.com/fByn1tTZ for HTML this pastebin.com/7HSMtEzu THANKS css https://pastebin.com/kKFF2cHM

Comment: I've edited my answer,  and you should use https://jsfiddle.net/ for sharing code it becomes more convenient for both ends.